# There is no MTS object context with ASPPDFLib in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When trying to convert a page to pdf, the page returns this YSOD error:

```
Obtaining Object Context failed: There is no MTS object context

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Obtaining Object Context failed: There is no MTS object context
```

And it took me quite a while to figure out, so hope I help someone someday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this is including **AspCompat="True"** on top of the page alongside @Page